# How can I create a variable in __main__ that can be used by web.py classes defined in the same file?

Tags: python, scope, web.py

I use the built-in webserver from web.py and **not** apache like in this question: [Global variable usage with web.py in Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16217322/global-variable-usage-with-web-py-in-apache)

I have this web service that takes a number as argument, adds it to an internal variable `number` and returns that variable.

Here's how the script looks like:

```
import web
import sys

urls = (
    '/(\d+)', 'Number'
)

class Number:
    def GET(self, parameter):
        # I want to read and write to the variable number here

        print "number in web service is " + str(number)

        number = number + int(parameter)
        return number


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #print sys.argv

    # I want to initialise the variable number here, based on command line parameter

    number = int(sys.argv[2]) if len(sys.argv) >= 3 else 0 # initialisation

    print "number init value " + str(number)

    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```

I start the server like so:

```
sudo python test.py 192.168.0.100 16
```

Where `16` is the initial value for the internal counter.

When executed like so:

```
http://192.168.0.100:8080/42
```

I get an `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'number' referenced before assignment` on this line

```
print "number in web service is " + str(number)
```

Ok, so I need `global`, because I don't want `number` to be a local variable of the service, I change to:

```
import web
import sys

urls = (
    '/(\d+)', 'Number'
)

class Number:
    def GET(self, parameter):
        # I want to read and write to the variable number here

        global number # number is not a lcoal variable

        print "number in web service is " + str(number)

        number = number + int(parameter)
        return number


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #print sys.argv

    # I want to initialise the variable number here, based on command line parameter

    number = int(sys.argv[2]) if len(sys.argv) >= 3 else 0 # initialisation

    print "number init value " + str(number)

    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```

Now I get a different error when calling the service on the same line `NameError: global name 'number' is not defined`. To fix this, I add an initialization at the top:

```
import web
import sys

urls = (
    '/(\d+)', 'Number'
)

number = 0 # assigning value to define variable

class Number:
    def GET(self, parameter):
        # I want to read and write to the variable number here

        global number # number is not a lcoal variable

        print "number in web service is " + str(number)

        number = number + int(parameter)
        return number


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #print sys.argv

    # I want to initialise the variable number here, based on command line parameter

    number = int(sys.argv[2]) if len(sys.argv) >= 3 else 0 # initialisation

    print "number init value " + str(number)

    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```

While I do not receive an error now, the logic is broken. While the initial print displays that `number init value is 16`, the other print does not have the same value, it says `number in web service is 0`.

Apparently, there are two separate `number` variables in my code. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4775596/4347580) that states that `__main__` is a separate module. Now that explains the different values for `number`. **However**, when I try to add `global` to `__main__`, like so:

```
import web
import sys

urls = (
    '/(\d+)', 'Number'
)

number = 0 # assigning value to define variable

class Number:
    def GET(self, parameter):
        # I want to read and write to the variable number here

        global number # number is not a lcoal variable

        print "number in web service is " + str(number)

        number = number + int(parameter)
        return number


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #print sys.argv

    # I want to initialise the variable number here, based on command line parameter

    global number # I want that one global variable number
    number = int(sys.argv[2]) if len(sys.argv) >= 3 else 0 # initialisation

    print "number init value " + str(number)

    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```

The value is again 16 upon initialization and 0 on the service.
I get a `SyntaxWarning: name 'number' is assigned to before global declaration` on that new line in `__main__`

So I got rid of the assignment on the top again, which wasn't really necessary in the first place. because the real initialization happens in `__main__`:

```
import web
import sys

urls = (
    '/(\d+)', 'Number'
)

class Number:
    def GET(self, parameter):
        # I want to read and write to the variable number here

        global number # number is not a lcoal variable

        print "number in web service is " + str(number)

        number = number + int(parameter)
        return number


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #print sys.argv

    # I want to initialise the variable number here, based on command line parameter

    global number # I want that one global variable number
    number = int(sys.argv[2]) if len(sys.argv) >= 3 else 0 # initialisation

    print "number init value " + str(number)

    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```

While that executes without warnings initially, I do get a `NameError global name 'number' is not defined` from the `GET` method.

**How do I create a variable that I can set in `__main__` and that I can also read and write to from a method of a class that's defined in the same file?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because of the auto-re-loader just put it on the top of the file and everything *should* work

```
import web
import sys



number = int(sys.argv[2]) if len(sys.argv) >= 3 else 0 #initialisation

urls = (
'/(\d+)', 'Number'
)

 ... #the rest of the file
```

You see, the re-loader will do "reload(yourmodule)" so the __main__ part won't be called again :(

Cheers